# My Windows 7 PC wakes up randomly and powercfg lastwake shows nothing. What to do?

Tags: windows-7, sleep, wake-up, powercfg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Laptop randomly waking up = Hibernate / Low Battery?](https://superuser.com/questions/464578/laptop-randomly-waking-up-hibernate-low-battery)

My PC wakes up from sleep randomly.

I disabled Hibernation after Sleep.

I am using Asus N53SV with Windows 7 64 bit.

Power Options > Sleep > Allow wake timers are disabled.

It doesn't wake up from Hibernation.

My searches yielded "Look for powercfg lastwake", "Disable wake timers" but they didn't help me.

**powercfg lastwake** shows this:

> Wake History Count - 1
>
> Wake History [0]
>
> Wake Source Count - 0

**PowerCfg -DEVICEQUERY wake_armed** shows this:

> HID Keyboard Device (001)

Which is normal since keyboard should wake up when pressed. The PC wakes up even when the lid is closed, so keyboard is not pressed.

**powercfg -energy** shows

> System Availability Requests:System Required Request
>
> The device or driver has made a request to prevent the system from automatically entering sleep.
>
> Requesting Driver Instance HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0269&SUBSYS_10431063&REV_1001\4&cc8e931&0&0001
>
> Requesting Driver Device   Realtek High Definition Audio

I'm using the latest Realtek driver

So what should I try next?

Comment: Sounds like a case of insomnia...

Comment: Duplicate of what?

Comment: Some people think it's duplicate of the link below. You can also see this link next to the number of votes. http://superuser.com/questions/464578/laptop-randomly-waking-up-hibernate-low-battery

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me yesterday. I checked online for a solution and found mention of applying the Visual Studio 2010 update [KB2764593](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2764593) being a solution, but I don’t have VS2010 installed.

I eventually figured out that the problem was caused by a failure of my Intel network adapter.
Please check the Windows Update.

Comment: Thanks, I always download the latest updates. No change yet.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify what happens when it wakes up (does it stay on or does it turn off after a minute?), but since you mentioned a “lid”, thus implying it is a laptop, combined with the lack of `lastwake` history, then it probably [the same issue](https://superuser.com/questions/464578/) that I investigated earlier this year.

If so, then chances are good that it is not *really* random. What’s probably happening is that the system is switching from sleep mode to hibernation mode after a specific, but long amount of time (e.g., six or 12 hours), and by putting the system to sleep at different times, the switch happens at a *seemingly* random time.

For example, if the system is set to switch after six hours and you put your system to sleep at 6pm, then it will wake up at midnight. If you then sleep it at 7:45pm the next day, it will wake up at 1:45pm, which *looks* random, especially in the middle of the night.

This seeming randomness is exacerbated by the fact that the transition timeout period is different for battery and AC power. So even if you always sleep it at about the same time, it can be different (by several hours) if you happen to have it plugged in one day and unplugged the next.

The issue is that by disabling hybrid-sleep, the system is *not supposed to* switch from standby to hibernation, but that setting does not seem to work and it *always* wakes up to hibernate.

What you can do is to modify your power-configuration profiles to set the hibernation to be the same as the sleep setting or (not recommended) just disable it altogether. Either way, make sure to change it for **all power profiles and modes**, that is, for *Power Saver*, *Balanceed*, and *High Performance* (and any others you created) and for each profile, set it for both *Battery* and *Online* modes.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Synetech. I forgot to mention in my question that I disabled hibernation after sleep. I will try the logging method.