# Windows waking from Sleep/Hibernation after 15-25 minutes

Tags: windows-8, sleep, hibernate, windows-10, wake-up

My machine is waking every 15-25 minutes after they are put into sleep/hibernation (issue persists with both). I'm running Windows 10 right now, but the issue was already present in Windows 8.1 (and hence I upgraded, hoping to fix the issue).

I know it is not the first time this issue has surfaced. But after looking for a solution for multiple hours, no solution came up. Here's what I tried so far:

### 1. Turn off "Allow this device to wake the computer"

I've turned off this option for every single device in the device manager. `powercfg -devicequery wake_armed` returns `NONE`.

[image]

`Lastwake` doesn't yield anything useful either.
[image]

### 2. Disabled wake timers

[image]

Also, Multimedia settings -> When sharing media -> Allow the computer to sleep.

### 3. Don't allow automatic maintenance to wake up PC

[image]

### 4. Power-Troubleshooter: All Wake Sources unknown

This is especially frustrating. Every single entry shows an unknown wake source.
[image]

### 5. BIOS: Disable Wake

My motherboard is a MSI Z87-G43 (unfortunately I can't take a screenshot of the BIOS).

### 6. Task-Scheduler: No tasks waking the PC

[image]

### 7. Remove Ethernet cable

I've unplugged the Ethernet cable before going to sleep/hibernation. No effect.

### 8. Energy report

[image]

No devices have "made a request to prevent the system from automatically entering sleep."

---

Does anyone know how to fix the issue?

Comment: Relevant: [My Windows 7 PC wakes up randomly and powercfg lastwake shows nothing. What to do?](https://superuser.com/q/506833)