# PC waking from sleep for unknown reason

Tags: windows-10, power-management, wake-on-lan

I recently started experiencing an issue with my PC, which runs Windows 10 Pro. It wakes from hibernation at seemingly random times. I have done the following to try and troubleshoot the issue:

- Turn off wake timers
- Disable all peripherals from waking the system
- Unplug network cable (No Wi-Fi)
- Try another power outlet

The computer still wakes at random times. When issuing the command

```
powercfg /lastwake
```

I get the following:

```
Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
    Wake Source Count - 0
```

I absolutely need *Wake on LAN* to work on the system, and it always has before. This issue only started recently.

Comment: Relevant: [My Windows 7 PC wakes up randomly and powercfg lastwake shows nothing. What to do?](https://superuser.com/q/506833)

Comment: Relevant: [Help me find the offending process waking my Windows 7 PC from hibernate every night](https://superuser.com/q/103380)

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm afraid neither of those questions you just posted was of any help.

I just tried increasing the timeout to go from sleep to hibernate. Though it never woke up exactly the amount of time after sleeping specified in the settings.

Comment: Have a look at this discussion [Windows 10 wakes randomly](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_perf/windows-10-wakes-randomly-from-hibernate/247e69c3-cc7a-40db-b34e-43d8d60e6947?auth=1) whether this helps you with some idea.

Comment: Duplicate. http://superuser.com/questions/951247/windows-waking-from-sleep-hibernation-after-15-25-minutes

Comment: And another one: http://superuser.com/questions/464578/laptop-randomly-waking-up-hibernate-low-battery

Comment: Also see http://superuser.com/a/1014580/384183

Comment: July 2018. There is NO powerdownETC option under Winlogon. It only has AlternativeShells; AutoLogonChecked; GPExtension (expandable with 100+ lists of numbers); VolatileUserMgrKey (mine is set to 1).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue was caused by TeamViewer, it creates wake timers that are somehow ran(?) even though wake timers are disabled. Even shutting down TeamViewer doesn't solve the issue for me. But uninstalling TeamViewer resolved the issue.

Comment: How did you determine this is what caused it to wake?

Comment: @smerny - I found it [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_perf/windows-10-wakes-randomly-from-hibernate/247e69c3-cc7a-40db-b34e-43d8d60e6947?auth=1&rtAction=1440617857797), Look for an answer by GBoDH containing TeamViewer (the only answer containing TeamViewer on that page)

Comment: I don't have teamviewer installed, and can't find Realtek (or any other) PCIE controller on my machine. Yet the darn computer keeps restarting.

Answer (score 21):

I found that it was the "Allow Wake Timers" detailed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/958109/how-to-prevent-windows-10-waking-from-sleep-when-traveling-in-bag#_=_).

> This has worked for me so far. Go to:
>
> Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\Edit Plan Settings
>
> Click "Change advanced power settings"
>
> Go to "Sleep->Allow wake timers" and change the setting to Disable.

And also from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3gd066/computer_wakes_up_every_night_from_sleep/).

> Go to Task Scheduler
>
> Find NT TASK\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot
>
> Its actually just named Reboot but you have to go inside those folders
>
> Right Click > Properties > Conditions
>
> Uncheck Wake the computer to run this task

Comment: Didn't work for me :(

Comment: Disabling wake timers didn't solve the problem for me. It turned out Teamviewer was ignoring the setting (how does a program overrule an OS setting again?) and rebooting anyway. It seems to be solved in the later versions.

Comment: In addition to this, I had the mouse and the keyboard set as allowed to wake the PC. both of bad quality which kept always on regardless of the PC power status. Disabling both features gave me the working solution in my case

Comment: Also makes sense to remove NTFS write permissions from this task for all accounts (including SYSTEM). This way updates will not re-enable the wake condition again. The file is located here: C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator

Comment: what do I do if Task Scheduler is started as admin but it requires a user and password to change the settings? A user/password that I don't have (user is S-1-5-18, whatever that is)

Comment: @jcollum Use `psexec` to start cmd as SYSTEM (the user with SID S-1-5-18), then open the task scheduler from that cmd (using `taskschd.msc` command), then perform the changes in that one. Note that `psexec` needs to run as administrator, so it can do its magic.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to see which devices are able to wake up the computer :

```
powercfg -devicequery wake_armed
```

And then, try to deactivate this device related privilege in devmgmt.msc

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not possible to solve it. When some Windows updates are pending due a computer restart and the computer is in hibernate mode, it automatically turns on at the scheduled time to restart. You must restart Windows manually, but if another update requires restart and you don't restart imediatelly, when you put the computer to hibernate, at the next time scheduled to restart , the computer will turn on again. Nevertheless, it is possible to change the schedule time to a period when the computer is normally turned on.

Comment: How do you change the scheduled time?

Comment: "I don't think a fix is possible" isn't really an answer, unless you really support why it isn't possible. Because there are many reasons this could be happening -- not just Windows updates -- proving that a fix isn't possible would be difficult and tedious.

Answer (score -1):

FOUND THE PROBLEM:

edit the registry Key hkey_local_machine\software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinLogon and modify PowerdownAfterShutdown and change it to 1

Source: Windows 10 wakes randomly from hibernate - Microsoft Community
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_perf/windows-10-wakes-randomly-from-hibernate/247e69c3-cc7a-40db-b34e-43d8d60e6947?auth=1

Summary: this setting prevents the computer from fully powering down upon "hibernation" if it's set to 0. 
Response: Who knew there would be any question? But apparently it's one more straw in the nest. If it doesn't work - I'll be back. Upvote please.

My Original post (background facts and personal peeves and observations):

Also have situation - with no teamviewer. The O.S. settings are being ignored, and no WAKE shows up in powercfg -lastwake. At first I thought that there was some intent to wake it - we all did. That is not true - it is just failing to power down. Note that this error is a prime security issue. And, it is standard operating procedure for Microsoft with its impossibly arbitrary levels of complexity, to create the situation incidentally (not accidentally.) They weren't happy with just being impossibly stupid since the browser wars - they had to double down again and again. Someone needs to go in that place and seriously reformat their drive.

Comment: PARTIAL ANSWER RETRACTION. WORKAROUND.
Due to the severe nature of this security issue, if your system persists in waking, after you have done the above steps, use this procedure: enter hibernation, and on shut down PULL THE PLUG and THE BATTERY (for laptops.)  
IMPORTANT STARTUP ISSUE: reinstall battery / plug in the machine. IT MAY IMMEDIATELY RESTART - wait for it. Do not touch anything except to turn on your monitor. IF NOT, then press the power button / resume key. IT SHOULD RESUME NORMALLY, EITHER WAY.

Comment: CAUTION: Users who are not familiar with editing the Windows Registry should proceed with caution, as making changes to it can have big consequences for your system.