# Computer waking up from sleep by itself

Tags: windows-8.1, sleep, power-management

My PC, running Windows 8.1, is waking up from sleep by itself.

I have wake-up timers disabled:

[image]

And there should be no hardware that is allowed to wake my device:

[image]

In the second picture, we do see TeamViewer having scheduled a wake-up timer, but since those are disabled, this shouldn't be the problem, right?

I have BitDefender installed and I noticed it was scanning after the system woke. This isn't every time though, and I've had BitDefender for about 1.5 years now, while the unsolicited wake-up problem is pretty new.

**Update:** A suggestion in the answers was running [Keith Hill's PowerShell script to analyze the PC's sleep behavior](https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2013/05/08/using-powershell-to-analyze-your-pcs-sleep-wake-behavior/). The result can be seen below. The marked line was a test, letting it wake up by itself. Source: 0

[image]

What causes this computer to wake up?

Comment: I have this problem too. My PC just wakes randomly when it's sleeping. My solution is to unplug the ethernet cable. No more random waking-ups after.

Comment: Have a look at the event viewer when it just woke up. This might give you an insight in why your PC is waking up.

Comment: Hmmm. Well if it's waking up on LAN, wouldn't that show up as the reason for "lastwake" and "devicequery wake_armed"? I just checked my Ethernet card in devices and Wake On Lan is disabled. 

If that WAS the problem for you, would you mind having a look under Device Manager > your network card > Advanced > Wake on LAN disabled what it's set to?

Comment: Since you mention Team Viewer, you may want to take a look at this: [Windows 10 waking from sleep with unknown reason](http://superuser.com/a/958029/174950)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PC waking from sleep for unknown reason](https://superuser.com/questions/955262/pc-waking-from-sleep-for-unknown-reason)

Comment: @music2myear Do you have a script that crawls stackoverflow and uses NLP to give you possible candidates for Possible duplicates?

Comment: No. I have a script that crawls SE and downloads the contents to my brain during periods of REM sleep every night. JK. I've been active on SU for a while (see my profile for dates) and have seen a lot of posts, so memory helps in some cases, SE surfaces suggested similar questions to the right of most questions and sometimes these turn out to be pretty close or duplicate, and sometimes I think that question must have been asked before and so I search and find duplicates.

Comment: Also, as a long-time technology professional, I'm pretty good and searching, and at interpreting words others use to try to communicate their errors into words and phrases others may have used to describe the same error, making web searches more effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was teamviewer after all. I still can't figure out why though. Wakeup timers were disabled in my powersettings. I also contacted teamviewer about the issue since, after some googling, this seems to be an old problem.

The ensured me this issue has been fixed a while ago. Well it's clearly still there or it re-emerged..

Anyways, CASE CLOSED, if you got a similar issue, use the powercfg tool to find the culprit! In my case teamviewer.

Answer (score 2):

Run the powershell ps1 file to parse your eventlogs @ https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2013/05/08/using-powershell-to-analyze-your-pcs-sleep-wake-behavior/

Or manually filter your system event logs for Power-Troubleshooter (1) and Kernel-Power (42) events. The wake source should be logged.

Comment: I tried the script but it came up with this: http://i.imgur.com/EGoHRG2.png . The marked line is a test I did. Putting it to sleep and letting it wake by itself. The Source does not show up though =/