# Windows 10 waking from sleep with no apparent reason

Tags: windows-10, sleep

I asked [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/955262/windows-10-waking-from-sleep-with-unknown-reason) about this a while back, and thought I solved the problem. Now It's come back!

The issue is that my computer will never stay asleep or hibernating for more than half an hour. Even when all waketimers are disabled, every program shut down and all devices disconnected so the only thing going into the computer is the power cord.

In my previous question, the culprit turned out to be Teamviewer. Just to be sure I uninstalled it but the issue still shows itself.

There are no devices that can wake the computer:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> powercfg -devicequery wake_armed
NONE
```

There are no wake timers

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> powercfg -waketimers
There are no active wake timers in the system.
```

Any help in fixing this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried creating and switching to a new default power profile?  Just try to use that for a while and see what happens.  Sometimes power profiles contain some things that are not apparent and it is easier to rule it out this way.  Next, look at your bios settings and see if there isn't something in there.

Comment: I had this happen to me for the longest time just over a year ago.  I disabled everything I could think of, waking on usb to win updates to anti-virus.  Eventually I had to reinstall Windows because Win 10 sucks anyway (for me) and problem solved.

Comment: @DaaBoss Thanks, it seems switching power profile fixed the issue. I was running some power profile setup by Samsung Magician (they say it contained some settings to improve SSD performance?). I switched back to High Performance and now it stays asleep for good. Go ahead and post this as answer for dat sweet sweet rep :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset the power profiles back to the original shipping configuration like this:

1. Save your current config to a new name, so you can reference it later.
2. Recreate or reset the DEFAULT settings for the profile[s] you want to use.
3. Make only a few changes that you document, so you can modify from the defaults, then monitor the results.

When PCs don't work as wanted or expected, power profiles are often at fault... Not the default profiles, but the profiles that have been modified by you or someone that uses your PC.  Changing to a new profile will often not work either, since often, those too were modified.   There are potentially a hundred settings, some of which are interrelated and can cancel out other settings.  So it is easy to make changes that can lead to unintended consequences.

At least you didn't have one of the more outrageous problems like Spotify putting a wake-up command in Windows Task Scheduler for no apparent benefit to the user.