# Windows 10 PC keeps waking up on its own at 4:05am

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep, power-management, wake-up

I usually keep my PC in sleep mode when I'm not using it. However, ever since I've upgraded it to Windows 10, I notice that the PC will wake up on its own in the middle of the night. Strangely, it will wake up *exactly* at 4:05am every night without fail!

I've followed through all the steps in an [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/973029/155358) on SU and this [thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/windows-10-keeps-waking-up-from-sleep-in-the/58052fd3-87fe-4457-aeaf-974b5ea15080) on MS forum, but my computer still wakes up every night at 4:05am.

It used to wake up, does what it wants to then return to sleep again. Recently, it has gotten worse as my PC doesn't return to sleep after waking up at 4:05am.

I've TeamViewer installed on my PC and I have read from an [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/958029/155358) from another question on SU that Teamviwer can wake up my PC from sleep every 30mins. However, in my case, my PC only wakes up at 4:05am. Also, I didn't have this problem when I was still on Windows 7.

This is very frustrating. What else can I check and do to stop my PC from waking up on its own in the middle of the night?

**Update:**

I tried looking at the Event Log and it seems like under the Windows Log/System, on every day at 4:05am, there were always these 3 events occurring:

1. The system time has changed to ‎2017‎-‎02‎-‎22T20:05:41.500000000Z from ‎2017‎-‎02‎-‎22T16:34:03.037707800Z.
2. Change Reason: System time synchronized with the hardware clock.
   Windows cannot store Bluetooth authentication codes (link keys) on
   the local adapter. Bluetooth keyboards might not work in the system
   BIOS during startup.
3. The access history in hive
   \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Boot\BCD was cleared updating 71 keys and
   creating 10 modified pages.

Comment: Is there anything in the event log which gives any clue?

Comment: Did you accidently set a scheduled task?

Comment: @Dave I have put in some of the events I found at 4:05am from the event log under "System".

Comment: @RamonRobben I don't think so. I have never scheduled any tasks so far.

Comment: Did you ever found a solution to your problem? This is bugging me since several months now, I've read virtually every resource to this and there's still no solution in sight!

Comment: @MarkusL well, the issue went away suddenly on its own but recently my computer started turning on itself again after a certain windows update.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that I don't have enough rep to comment but check this link for info regarding to hardware clock syncing.
https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/3gh1od/system_wakes_up_shortly_after_sleep_to_sync_time/

This link provides 2 possible workarounds, 1. disable an related services 2. check for waketimers by `powercfg /waketimers`

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured the problem out: It was indeed a scheduled task and Windows 10 is ignoring any settings (BIOS, power plan, ...) which prohibit to wake up your computer.

Indeed `powercfg /waketimers` gives you the hint. It was pointing to the **Task Scheduler Library** at `Microsoft\Windows\rempl\shell`. In there I had several tasks which were configured to *wake the computer to run this task*. I disabled the checkbox (see tab *Conditions*) and my computer finally stayed in hibernation. No more wake-ups at random times!

Ultimately the tasks run `remsh.exe`. According to some other forum posts this application may be installed by Windows Update but is not installed on every computer. So you may check out if the solution applies to your problem as well.