# Desktop computer wakes up after a few minutes

Tags: windows, sleep

Not sure what is causing it. Not sure what other information you all would need apart from what I'm pasting below.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg -devicequery wake_armed
NONE

C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg /lastwake
Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
Wake Source Count - 0
```

I am running "High Performance" in Power Options and I have disabled "Allow wake timers." I have also unchecked “Allow scheduled maintenance to wake up my computer at the scheduled time” in Action Center Maintenance.

What is causing these wakes? Can it be a Sony blu-ray device connected to the same wireless network? That's the only thing that has recently changed that I remember.

EDIT: Some more information:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laptop randomly waking up = Hibernate / Low Battery?](http://superuser.com/questions/464578/laptop-randomly-waking-up-hibernate-low-battery)

Comment: There may be options in the BIOS for this as well so check there.

Comment: I don't want to mess with BIOS options since I didn't change anything in the BIOS and sleep was working fine before.

My "Hibernate after" is set to "Never" as is "Sleep after." I disabled hybrid sleep but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Unplug the network cable, if it doesn't wake up, then you may have the NIC set to wake the computer on any traffic.

Comment: I don't have a network cable plugged in. I use a wireless Intel card since I built the computer and I never had a problem with it.