# Laptop wakes up from sleep every several hours

Tags: windows-10, sleep, power-management

I have a new ASUS Zenbook UX305.
OS: Windows 10 Home

I've figured out that my laptop wakes up from sleep during the night, so i reviewed the *event viewer* and found out that it happens about 3-4 times each night.

I searched the web, applying the following solutions:

- **Disabled** `Advanced Power Settings -> Sleep -> "Allow wake timers"`
- `powercfg -lastwake` shows the wake up trigger was the **power button**.
- In the device manager, I disabled the `"allow to wake up"` feature of the **mouse**, `"wake on lan"` and `"wake on pattern match"` of the **WAN adapter**.
- `powercfg -devicequery wake_armed` shows NONE.

And it still wakes up like a crying baby.

Comment: Looking at the BIOS menu for this machine, there is an option 'Wake on lid open'. I don't know whether a sensor is triggering oddly and firing it? It might be worth disabling that to see if there is any change in behavior anyway, and checking if there are any other wake settings in BIOS to help diagnose the problem.

Comment: @jonno I've already reviewed the BIOS searching for strange wake settings. I'll try your idea, although the "lid-wakeup" works fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/464578/laptop-randomly-waking-up-hibernate-low-battery?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://superuser.com/questions/973009/conclusively-stop-wake-timers-from-waking-windows-10-desktop](http://superuser.com/questions/973009/conclusively-stop-wake-timers-from-waking-windows-10-desktop)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found out that the laptop wakes up exactly **3 hours** after I put it to sleep, 
so I googled again using this new piece of data.

Paradoxically, my laptop (and probably many other laptops) **wakes up in order to hibernate**, but for some reason the **hibernation fails** - resulting with the laptop "staying awake".

### Solution

Right-click on the Start button and select "Power Options".

"Change when the computer sleeps" > "Change advanced power settings"

"Sleep" > "Hibernate after"

- On battery: Never
- Plugged in: Never

[image]

Source: [eightforums.com](http://www.eightforums.com/general-support/56175-what-waking-my-computer-after-precisely-3-hours.html)

Comment: This is a **workaround** (not actually a **solution**). If you keep the PC sleeping for a prolonged time, it will drain the battery.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio not at all. My laptop is not on battery when this happens so definitely solves a problem for me. Also, hibernation is disabled on my laptop so this setting should not be enabled anyway.

Comment: @HansLøken - Good to know.

Comment: I have a theory.  I had Hibernate un-checked from the "Choose what the power buttons do" menu, so the system was not supposed to actually hibernate, but all of my "Sleep -> Hibernate After" options were set to 3 hours, and I saw the same symptoms as above.  I just disabled Hibernate completely (`powercfg /h off`) so now "Sleep -> Hibernate After" is totally gone; hopefully, that stops the wee-hours wakeups.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did:

First run:

```
powercfg /lastwake
```

This might give something like:

```
Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
  Wake Source Count - 1
  Wake Source [0]
    Type: Device
    Instance Path: ACPI\ACPI000E\2&daba3ff&1
    Friendly Name:
    Description: ACPI Wake Alarm
    Manufacturer: (Standard system devices)
```

If you recognize device then you found the issue. In above case friendly name is missing so device is not recognizable but it seems that something capable of waking up the system did the trick (as opposed to faulty lid closer detection).

Run below command to see scheduled wake timers:

```
powercfg /waketimers
```

In my case this prints:

```
Timer set by [SERVICE] \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\svchost.exe (SystemEventsBroker) expires at 6:41:31 PM on 12/10/2019.
  Reason: Windows will execute 'NT TASK\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Backup Scan' scheduled task that requested waking the computer.
```

You can run Task Scheduler built-in to Windows, navigate to above path and see if this is problematic.

Next thing to try is simply disable devices that can wake up the computer. Run following:

```
powercfg -devicequery wake_armed
```

Typically devices such as `NVIDIA USB Type-C Port Policy Controller`, `NVidia High Definition Audio` etc might popup here. Go to Device Manager, find these devices under Sound, USB etc sections, look for "Wake" in their properties and disable it. Also, WiFi controllers have ability to wake up the system. You can disable that in Device Manager as well. Finally, in Power Settings, go to Sleep section and disable Allow wake timers setting.

Comment: I have the "NVIDIA USB Type-C Port Policy Controller" and I have unchecked the wake option, but it seems to reactivate itself after reboot. Is there any way you know of it make that change permanent?

Answer (score 0):

The NVIDIA USB Type-C Port Policy Controller thing is troublesome. As you say it flicks itself back on after a reboot even if you uncheck "Allow this Device to wake the Computer".

You can work around it by making a batch file that runs on startup with the command "powercfg -devicedisablewake "NVIDIA USB Type-C Port Policy Controller". That will uncheck the box. Not the most elegant of solutions to be fair.

If you're don't use the Type C port on the video card you can uninstall the device entirely. However when you update the driver it will probably reinstall it.