# PC keeps waking up - ACPI wake alarms refuse to be disabled

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep, scheduled-tasks, wake-up

Good morning.

Every night my Windows 10 PC wakes up, and thus wakes me up, at least once. Event Viewer shows the Wake Source as "Device - ACPI Wake Alarm". This despite my best efforts to disable ACPI wake alarms, and the fact that I can't find any active alarms.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Steps taken:

- In Power Management, I have set wake timers to "Disable"
- In Security and Maintenance, I have ensured "Wake computer" is unchecked.
- In Task Scheduler, I have taken ownership of the relevant UpdateOrchestrator tasks, and unchecked "Wake computer".
- I have used Task Scheduler View to check that there are no tasks with "Wake to Run" checked.
- Running "powercfg /waketimers" shows no active waketimers.
- Running "Get-ScheduledTask | where {$_.settings.waketorun}" in Powershell shows two tasks, both in "Disabled" state.
- Running "powercfg /devicequery wake_armed" shows only the mouse and keyboard.
- I have even reinstalled Windows, just in case something weird was up with the old install.

I have referred to the following sources but after trying all the suggestions I am no closer to a solution

- https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/burul7/desktop_keeps_waking_itself_from_sleep_acpi_wake/
- [Conclusively stop wake timers from waking Windows 10 desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/973009/conclusively-stop-wake-timers-from-waking-windows-10-desktop)
- [How to tell what wake source is when Wake Source: Unknown](https://superuser.com/questions/1069700/how-to-tell-what-wake-source-is-when-wake-source-unknown)
- https://www.vistax64.com/threads/power-options-and-sleep-mode-problems.63567/

Comment: Are you sure there is no mouse/keyboard that wake up the PC? You can use hibernate before the problem is solved.

Comment: Take a look at this [page](https://www.howtogeek.com/170716/how-to-stop-network-activity-from-waking-your-windows-pc/)

Comment: What do you mean with "Reinstalled" exactly? - *I have even reinstalled Windows, just in case something weird was up with the old install.*  - Did you installed Windows new and later used a safety copy of the old system or did you installed also all your required applications new on a fresh and independent windows installation?

Comment: Yes I am sure no mouse/keyboard can wake the PC accidentally. That would show up in the event viewer. Also, hibernate does not solve the problem because ACPI wake alarms wake the PC even in hibernate. When hibernating the PC still wakes me up. :)

Comment: By "reinstalled Windows", I mean I performed a fresh install. I did not restore a backup.

Comment: I did check all network cards and disabled their ability to wake the PC. As mentioned in my original post only mouse and keyboard have the ability to wake the PC.

Comment: spike_66, thanks for the link. However the network card can not wake my system. I unchecked the appropriate box.

As I mentioned, running "powercfg /devicequery wake_armed" shows only the mouse and keyboard.

Comment: Other [tips](https://windowsreport.com/windows-8-windows-10-wakes-sleep-fix/) related to this issue

Comment: spike_66, thanks for the link. I had tried everything except disabling the UsoSvc service. Let's see if that helps. :)

Comment: Hi again. I'm still having this issue. This wake timer comes up from time to time. "Timer set by [SERVICE] \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\svchost.exe (SystemEventsBroker) expires at 22:58:30 on 1/02/2020.
  Reason: Windows will execute 'NT TASK\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Universal Orchestrator Start' scheduled task that requested waking the computer." In Task Scheduler it does indeed show "Wake the Computer to run this task." So far I've been unable to change the task even with psexcc. Any ideas?

Comment: I've now taken ownership of the file and unchecked "Wake the Computer" in the task using psexec. We shall see.

Comment: Fun wrinkle: If I take ownership of the "Universal Orchestrator Start" file and then remove "Wake the Computer to run this task," Windows creates a new file after a day or two, and then reinstates the task including "Wake..."

Comment: I was getting mystery wakeup from the "ACPI Wake Timer" device, then I found [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1033409/18694) which led me to notice that the wakeup was exactly 3 hours after it went to sleep -- per the "Sleep -> Hibernate After" setting.  It had to "wake up" to start hibernating, but always failed for some reason.  I just disabled hibernation completely with `powercfg /h off` and I'm hoping that solves it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately that doesn't solve it as my machine was going from sleep to hibernate after only an hour, but was waking up again in the middle of the night.

At this point I just use hibernate when I go to bed. That keeps her quiet. :)

Answer (score 4):

The wake up alarm is due to the hibernating after sleep

1. [Open Power Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNKER.png)
2. [Change plan settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJLXN.png)
3. [Change advanced power settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZCW9.png)
4. [Change "Sleep" > "Hibernate after" values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lx0F6.png)
5. Goto sleep state
6. Wake up
7. Run in terminal: `powercfg /SLEEPSTUDY`
8. Open created file `C:\WINDOWS\system32\sleepstudy-report.html`
9. [Find latest section (near the bottom)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDEEt.png)
10. The diff time == the hibernate after time

Comment: This was my case. I think some update must have reset my power settings, because I had auto-turn-off screen and auto-sleep, and I _never_ want these things to happen in my desktop PC. When I turned those off, I was able to turn off auto-hibernate too, and then my PC stopped waking up. Thanks!

Comment: That report is golden, thank you so much. It was driving me nuts, my PC was not going to hibernate after sleep it was already disabled. I found a log in that report for `\HP\HP Print Scan Doctor\Printer Health Monitor` waking my PC and now I need to violently murder some HP software.