# Windows 10: troubleshooting Wake Source

Tags: windows-10, laptop, sleep, battery, hibernate

My laptop randomly wakes up in the middle of the night, and stays on. I asked a question about this, [Hibernating laptop randomly wakes up and stays on when lid is closed](https://superuser.com/questions/1143209/hibernating-laptop-randomly-wakes-up-and-stays-on-when-lid-is-closed) and that gave me a way in to troubleshoot the issue. But I'm baffled by what I've found.

This is what my event log says is happening:

```
The system has returned from a low power state.

Sleep Time: ‎2016‎-‎11‎-‎08T22:25:45.587472800Z
Wake Time: ‎2016‎-‎11‎-‎09T01:24:32.122549700Z

Wake Source: Power Button

=====

The system has returned from a low power state.

Sleep Time: ‎2016‎-‎11‎-‎09T22:26:23.256132700Z
Wake Time: ‎2016‎-‎11‎-‎10T01:26:27.966035400Z

Wake Source: Power Button

=======

The system has returned from a low power state.

Sleep Time: ‎2016‎-‎11‎-‎10T22:25:45.587472800Z
Wake Time: ‎2016‎-‎11‎-‎11T01:25:49.136282200Z

Wake Source: Power Button
```

Now, that's not a human being pressing the power button. I learned elsewhere that other power events are sometimes mis-reported as coming from the power button, specifically magic packet wake-up calls. So I disabled that, but it's still happening. And if it's any help, I can see there's mis-reporting going on in the lops because it registers wake-ups from the lid opening as being sources on the power button.

So here's what I've got in terms of information:

- System wakes up at roughly - but not exactly - the same time.
- This *only* happens when it's plugged into the power. I scoured the logs to see if it was waking and then going back to sleep when not charging but there's nothing there.
- System claims it's being awoken by the power button, but it's certainly misreporting the wake up source at least some of the time. It is reporting some Wake Timers and Scheduled Tasks but these seem to run normally: the task happens, the PC goes back to sleep.

What else can I do to troubleshoot?

Comment: Use `powercfg /devicequery wake_armed` to display list of devices that could wake your machine. Then try to disable them using `powercfg /devicedisablewake <device name>`.

Comment: As you say random it's not happening every day, is it? In that case it might be Windows Update as it's trying to install updates. Usually (assuming nothing fancy is running) it should install the updates and go back to sleep. Check your activity hour settings for the Windows update and correlate them to the wake up time. Change them to be out of your sleeping time and/or reboot your system more often and don't just use hibernate if you do that.