# Windows 10 HP awakes from hibernation after charge finishes

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks, wake-up

A recently acquired HP (15s-fq1xxx) running Windows 10 is frequently kept in hibernation rather than shut down. If during hibernation is being charged, it will wake after finishing (I have not checked if it happens in case it was shut down).

I tried to diagnose this behaviour myself, with some help from [SE](https://superuser.com/questions/1258473/display-all-power-related-events-turn-on-off-sleep-hibernate), but every solution found in sites like [here](https://superuser.com/questions/958109/how-to-prevent-windows-10-waking-from-sleep-when-traveling-in-bag/1014580#1014580), [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1143209/hibernating-laptop-randomly-wakes-up-and-stays-on-when-lid-is-closed), or [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/122954/how-to-prevent-your-computer-from-waking-up-accidentally/), were useless.

[energy log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUhEw.png)

On the other hand, `powercfg -devicequery wake_armed` shows `HID compatible mouse`, while the device manager shows every HID and mouse available energy management tab configured to not allow them to wake the computer.

In addition, the Event Viewer shows info for some of these events, with reasons ranging from "Unknown", to programmed tasks like:
'NT TASK\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Schedule Wake To Work'
or
'NT TASK\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Policy Install'

Any further suggestions?

Comment: I just found a possible solution for some of the events, related to an enabled energy configuration (under power Plan Settings>Change advanced power settings>Sleep>Allow wake timers).

Comment: What says `powercfg /lastwake`?

Comment: @harrymc it says power button because I found it suspended in the morning :(

Comment: What does it say after waking from hibernation when charging finishes?

Comment: @harrymc I've been waiting for another start under these conditions to check it but it seems no longer happening. The reason could be I changed the power plan disabling: Advanced>Sleep->Allow wake timers. I probably bypassed this setting as what I do is more specifically hibernating the computer, instead of sleeping it. I'll keep watching for this behaviour.